# How to fetch data each time user opens the screen and update the state only if the fetched data is different than the current data in state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am relatively new to react, react native and redux and I have one question about fetching the data from the api and updating the state.

What I want to do is:
- each time a user opens the screen (i.e Posts) I want to fetch data from the api and update the state.

So that:
- I always have newly fetched data in the state and rendered on the screen.

If I fetch the data only in componentDidMount lifecycle method then I won't always have fresh data.

Example:
There are two screens Post and Posts. If a user opens posts screen for the first time then componentDidMount is triggered and posts are fetched and rendered. Then he goes to Post screen adds a new post and goes back to Posts screen then he will not see that new post because the posts will be displayed from the state fetched in componentDidMount method.

What is the best way to handle this and always have latest data?

```
class Posts extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchPosts();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        this.props.fetchPosts();
    }

    render () { ... }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        posts: state.posts.posts,
        loading: state.posts.loading,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
     return {
         fetchPosts: () => dispatch(actions.fetchPosts()),
     }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Posts)
```

---

Action

```
export const fetchPosts = () => {
    return dispatch => {

         dispatch(fetchStarted());

         apiFetchPosts()
         .then(({data}) => {

             const posts = data.data;

             dispatch(fetched(posts))
         })
         .catch(error => {
             dispatch(fetchFailed(error));
         })
     }
 }

 const fetchStarted = () => {
      return {
         type: actionTypes.POSTS_FETCH_START,
      }
 }

 const fetched = (posts) => {
      return {
           type: actionTypes.POSTS_FETCH_SUCCESS,
           posts,
      }
 }

 const fetchFailed = (error) => {
     return {
         type: actionTypes.POSTS_FETCH_FAILED,
     }
 }
```

Comment: How do you go to one screen to the other? Could you post the content of `Post.js` and `Posts.js`?

Comment: Two basic stateful components exported with connect from react-redux and mapped state and dispatch to props. I navigate using react native navigation. I set the **ref** in App component and use it to navigate to screens instead of calling it with this.props.navigation.navigate(...) in component.

Comment: I think he wants when adding some post in Post.js and go back to the previous screen Posts.js he wants to see his post added without refresh the app, like a Facebook posts

Comment: I want to fetch the data each time user visits that page. When Posts screen is rendered -> fetch data and render that data. But when I tried to combine componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate to make api call I ended up in an endless loop.

Comment: Please can you show us your code?

Comment: @DevAS I updated the original post and added the code. Only thing missing is reducer, do I need to add that too?

Answer (score 3):

#### Update as you go

In your case, you should be sending a `POST` request to insert a new post. That request should have the newly created post as a response. You should use that response to update the list of posts you have in the redux state. Simply add the new post to the list.

The same goes for removing posts, once you send a `DELETE` request, you should also remove that post from the state.

#### Add timed cache

If you want to refetch the posts when you haven't fetched it for a while, you should implement some kind of caching solution:

When you fetch the posts for the first time you can also store the timestamp of the request. When the user visits the Posts page, you can check if the timestamp is too old e.g. 5 minutes in the past, and refetch it accordingly.

#### Refetch everytime

If you want to simply refetch the posts every time the user visits that page, you can use the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook or a combination of `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.

**Please note:**

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop.
> [Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Comment: **Update as you go** is a fine solution but in my case. Because then if someone else adds a post this user will not see those new posts instead he will only see previous posts (fetched with componentDidMount) and the post he just added.I tried with componentDidMount + componentDidUpdate but I guess I am stuck with the check in componentDidUpdate method, I am not sure how to do it. The data I get from the api and how I store it in state is an array of objects. I will check out the **Refetch everytime**

Answer (score 1):

You could use `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: Well I forgot to mention that but I did try to use componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate and in both of those methods I call an action to fetch data, but I get an endless loop.

Comment: @mishke you should only update the state inside `componentDidUpdate` if the posts changed. Otherwise you will trigger updates every time, thus the infinite loop. I added an answer for your question above :+1: good luck